# The value of primary key in type uniqueidentifier doesn't change

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, uniqueidentifier

I created a database in visual studio 2010.

This database has a table that has 3 columns.

- AdId which is primary key and its type is uniqueidentifier
- AdName in type nvarchar
- UserId in type uniqueidntifier

When a user logs in and clicks on a button, I want a row adds to my database with

- a constant value for AdName (I determined it)
- logged in user's Id for User Id
- an Id created automatically by database for AdId

Everything is ok when a row added, but the value of AdId doesn't change in another time, this value is 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 all the time.

I know it's a silly question but I don't know where is the problm and what should I do. 
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Two things:

- Did you specify a default of NEWID() for AdId?
- Are you sending `00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000` or `0x00` (binary) to the database
  For example, `SELECT CAST(0x00 AS uniqueidentifier)`

Basically, SQL Server is doing what you asked

Comment: No I didn't specify default of NEWID() a didn't send 00...00 to database .

Comment: @Tena: then you need to set a default. There is some implied value of 0x00 being inserted

Comment: How can Iset default value? Did you mean Put a value in Identity seed? How can I specify a defult of NEWID()?

Comment: ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT DF_myTable_AdId DEFAULT NEWID() FOR AdId ;

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE myTable (
    myId uniqueidentifier NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE myTable ADD CONSTRAINT myConstraint
                        DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID()
                        FOR myId ;
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I use this code but I don't know why it isn't working!!

Answer (score 1):

Set default value for AdId column to `newid()`

Comment: Thanks fo aswer, I set Default Value or Bindng in Column Propertise to (newid()), but still doesn't work :(